# domain redirect to another domain with dns

Tags: redirect, dns

My domain with hosting plan: testing.com
Other domains, but without hosting plan: test.com and test2.com
All of them buyed on same company, so NS records same.

Maybe DNS type A would help in this situation ?

In short, if someone try to use test.com or test2.com all users would be redirected to testing.com

Comment: Probably belongs to serverfault or webmasters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you talking about web-hosting. If your hosting plan is name-based virtualhosting (and that is what you probably have), The answer is: DNS is not enough.

You have two options:

1. Add multiple domain names to your hosting (most hostings will allow this either for free up to N domains, or for some additional fee or as part of more expensive plan).
2. Use URL forwarding (aka URL redirection) service, like [this one](http://www.domain.com/domains/tools.php) (there are plenty other providers as well).

With both methods, you need appropriate DNS records in your domains, it can probably be handled by either - hosting for option 1, or URL forwarding provider for option 2. Basically you will need A records pointing either to your hosting, or URL forwarding webserver.